# How to convert this file to xml

Tags: xml, symfony, yaml

How to convert this file to xml?

```
    sonata.admin.builderhomepage:
        class: XXX\AdminBundle\Admin\BuilderHomePageAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "CateOgo", label: "BHCarousel" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - XXX\FrontendBundle\Entity\BuilderHomePage
            - PixSortableBehaviorBundle:SortableAdmin
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
            - [ setPositionService, [@pix_sortable_behavior.position]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks but this not worked , I have fix this :-

```
        <service id="sonata.admin.builderhomepage" class="XXX\AdminBundle\Admin\BuilderHomePageAdmin">
        <tag name="sonata.admin" manager_type="orm" group="CateOgo" label="BHCarousel"/>
        <argument />
        <argument>XXX\FrontendBundle\Entity\BuilderHomePage</argument>
        <argument>PixSortableBehaviorBundle:SortableAdmin</argument>
        <call method="setContainer">
              <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
        </call>
        <call method="setPositionService">
              <argument type="service" id="pix_sortable_behavior.position" />
        </call>
    </service>
```